# How to keep the space between tick and label minimum?

Tags: r, plot, graph, label

i've got a tiny problem in here, which i would like to have some hints on.

How can i change the space between ticks and labels? (indicated with 1 & 2)

[image]

> my current structure looks as follows:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,2),oma=c(0,0,2,0),las=1,mar=c(3,5,2,1),cex.lab=0.9, cex.axis=0.7)
plot(sapply(ERRORS.train.fast[[1]],mean),main="Pipe 63569",type="l", ylab="", xlab="",xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:29,labels=seq(2,30,1))
title(ylab= "RMSE (-)",line=3)
title(xlab= "K-Value",line=2)
```

highly appreciate your help!

cheers,
Olli

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `padj` argument for *"adjustment for each tick label perpendicular to the reading direction."* (from `?axis`)

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(1:5, axes = F)
axis(1)

plot(1:5, axes = F)
axis(1, padj = -.75)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the directions are different for the different axes (because it is relative what is "up" for the text), so to move the labels closer to the ticks, you will want *lower `padj` values* for the horizontal axis, but *higher `padj` values* for the vertical axis.

If you rotate the labels (as shown in your example plot on the vertical axis), you will use `hadj` instead of `padj`. Overall, I would expect you want something like:

```
plot(1:5, axes = F)
axis(1, padj = -.75)
axis(2, hadj = 0, las = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mpg` par.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species],
    ylab="", xlab="",xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:7)
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species],
    ylab="", xlab="", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:7, mgp=c(0,0.5,0))
```

[image: Two axes]